# How can I iterate in my dataframe putting an extra column and a value if some conditions are accomplished?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with over 8 millions records like this, product promotion It´s what you have to buy to get your reward, accumulation It´s what you have bought.

| Name | Product | Product Promotion | Reward | Accumulation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jhon | Prod1 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| Casandra | Prod2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

To cover any situation, I have a code, If some other conditions are met, too far I have a code like this but I´ts taking too long and I´m not getting the results I want to have.

```
for acummulation, promotion,reward in zip(df["Accumulation"], df["Product Promotion"],df["Reward"]):        
    if acummulation==reward:       
        df['ProductToRetire']=Reward
    elif acummulation>reward:
        df['ProductToRetire']=math.trunc(acummulation/promotion)*Reward
    else:
        df['ProductToRetire']=0
```

So my question is, It´s there anyway to itirate this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `np.select`

```py
df['ProductToRetire'] = np.select(
    [df['Accumulation'].eq(df['Reward']),
     df['Accumulation'].gt(df['Reward'])],
    [Reward,
     df['Accumulation'].div(df['Product Promotion']).apply(math.trunc).mul(Reward)],
    default=0
)
```